# A gift still being paid for

Tags: property, gift

So, I was gifted a drawing tablet specifically for me on Christmas. Nobody in our home also draws digitally besides me. We're having some family issues so we're trying to leave. But then again theyve said if we leave then they will keep our electronics. *(My siblings electronics too.)*
 They're still paying for my tablet atleast *(renting it sorta? I dont know,,)*. So can they take away the tablet they GAVE me for Christmas completely? They're still paying for it so I'm confused if I legally own it or not. I want to leave with my tablet cause it has ALL my photos, art, apps, everything. But I think they still own it due to them still paying for it. 
*(I'm sorry if this is confusing)*

Comment: Ouch, lots of problems here - do they have it on consumer credit (or credit card etc) or did they actually take it out on a lease-buy "deal"?  It matters because they may not actually own the item in some cases, so you may indeed not have legally been gifted it.  As an aside, I would recommend you back up any data you have on your tablet regardless of what happens, because having it solely on the tablet is just asking for it to be lost for a lot of very possible reasons.  Get a free Dropbox account and dump the data there.

Comment: This can't be answered effectively without a lot more details, and having those details makes the question unsuitable for Stack Exchange. Either way, you really need to see a lawyer for legal resolution and other specialists for technical and interpersonal resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. Quite clearly, if you are given a gift, you can keep it. The question is: What exactly is the gift you received?

I might have borrowed £500 from my bank to buy a £500 tablet to give you as a gift. I have to repay the loan, but that’s my problem. The tablet is yours, the loan is between me and my bank.

I might have signed a contract where I paid a £100 deposit and have to pay £50 a month for the next 8 months, and on non-payment the company will take the tablet back. My gift to you was the £100 deposit, and every month I make another £50 gift. If I stop giving the further gifts you lose your tablet.

In that situation you won’t be able to force me to make further £50 gifts, so either you make further payments yourself or lose the tablet.